# Copying production database using Mysql

Tags: database, mysql

I have a huge production DB of around 30GB using Mysql present in remote machine. I want to make a copy of that DB on my local Mysql setup. But I don't want to use SQL dump files.

Is there any alternative to make a copy of production DB to my local machine without using SQL dump files? Please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 5.x - you may use replication mechanism to make "mirror" database. You can run replication, then stop slave database and back it up very fast without stopping master database.

If you want to use it for backup - you can find more information here:

[Using Replication for Backups at dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-backups.html)